# Getting error while sending mail using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, email

I am using the `sp_send_dbmail` stored procedure of SQL Server and often getting error message:

> Mail not queued. Database Mail is stopped. Use sysmail_start_sp to start Database Mail.

After that I used `EXECUTE dbo.sysmail_start_sp` to start email service again in SQL Server.

What could possibly be causing this error? Does anyone has any idea, then please let me know.

Comment: Did you check the SQL Server log?

Comment: how can i do that ? can you please provide query to do that

Comment: Type in `sql server log` in your favorite search engine, click the first link.

Comment: @TT. is there any way to check weather the mail service is running or stopped in sql server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will help you...found it from this URL[here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic822183-146-1.aspx)
After starting the service using sysmail_start_sp run the following script. This will solve the issue

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
Declare @ch uniqueidentifier;
Declare @message_type nvarchar(256);
Declare @message_body nvarchar(max);
Declare @ctr bigint;
Declare @ctr2 bigint;
While (1=1)
Begin
Receive @ch = conversation_handle, @message_type = message_type_name from ExternalMailQueue
set @ctr2 = @ctr2 + 1
set @ctr = (select count(*) from ExternalMailQueue)
if @ctr = 0 
break
end
```